# Activity Indicator loading

Tags: javascript, react-native

I have a question about the Activity Indicator.

In my signup page, when the signup button is clicked I put a loader. Now there is a problem, if someone insert data in the field to signup and some of these data are wrong but click in the signup button, the button change in a loader but it can't be clicked anymore. the only solution is to come back in the home and then go another time in the page for the signup. How can I do??

So the problem is when the button is clicked, because if some fields are wrong even if the data are changed it is not possible to register, because the key has turned into a loader.

```
<View style={style.inputContainer}>
            <TextInput
              style={style.inputs}
              placeholder="Email"
              placeholderTextColor="#56cbbe"
              keyboardType="email-address"
              underlineColorAndroid="grey"
              onChangeText={Email => this.setState({ Email })}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={style.inputContainer}>
            <TextInput
              style={[style.inputs]}
              placeholder="Password"
              placeholderTextColor="#56cbbe"
              secureTextEntry={true}
              underlineColorAndroid="grey"
              onChangeText={Password => this.setState({ Password })}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={style.inputContainer}>
            <TextInput
              style={style.inputs}
              placeholder="Verifica Password"
              placeholderTextColor="#56cbbe"
              secureTextEntry={true}
              underlineColorAndroid="grey"
              onChangeText={PasswordRepeat => this.setState({ PasswordRepeat })}
            />
          </View>
          <View style={style.footer}>
          {(!this.state.isLoading) ? <TouchableOpacity
              style={[style.button, style.buttonOK]}
              onPress={() => this.showLoader()}
            >
              <Text style={[style.buttonTesto]}>Signup</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity> : <ActivityIndicator animating={this.state.isLoading} size="large" color="#56cbbe" />}  // IT'S here!
          </View>
        </KeyboardAwareScrollView>
```

Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

a quick fix is to check your loading state whenever there is a change in textInput.

```
            <TextInput
              style={[style.inputs]}
              placeholder="Password"
              placeholderTextColor="#56cbbe"
              secureTextEntry={true}
              underlineColorAndroid="grey"
              onChangeText={ (Password) => {
                this.state.isLoading 
                ? 
                this.setState({ Password, isLoading: false })
                :
                this.setState({ Password })  
              }}
            />
```

this code is not tested, but it should work. Do the same for the rest of your input fields.

Alternatively, if you are using a UI library such as react-native-paper, they have button components that accept a loading parameter which you can easily toggle.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! What do you refer about "check your loading state" ? :)

Comment: onChangeText={ (Password) => {
                this.state.isLoading 
                ? 
                this.setState({ Password, isLoading: false })
                :
                this.setState({ Password })  
              }}

whenever this event occurs, it will refer back to your 'loading' state variable. if this.state.loading === true, then it will set it to false while also setting the input value.

Comment: Ok Thanks :) I'll trying! :D

Comment: I have tried what did you said, but I don't resolve the problem in all. For example if Insert only a field and click on signup button, I receive an error because the registration is incomplete, but the button is changed in a loader

Comment: onPress={() => {
// validate inputs here first.
this.showLoader()
}}